# Browser error about untrusted SSL certificate

Tags: ssl

i am getting this notice in the chrome console on every page that has google adsense on my site

The SSL certificate used to load resources from https://sync.mookie1.cn will be distrusted in M70

my domain has nothing to do with  https://sync.mookie1.cn , is it like a general message? or do i have to replace my SSL certificate?

my certificate is issued by commodo, i think they have nothing to do with that

let me know what you think

Comment: Something on your page is requesting a resource located on that domain. You need to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ad from an ad server that has certificate signed by an untrusted root certificate.

It might be from google or another ad network or your site might just be infected.

The only way to make it stop is to eliminate the reference to the site/page with the bad cert.

Comment: Hi
I do use adsense on my site, 
can i assume it's just a problem from their side?

Comment: You can do a "view HTML" and see if you can find the ad and what's inserting it.